# QuickSort: what is wrong with this implementation

Tags: java, quicksort

Can you explain what is wrong with this quicksort algorithm implementation in java?

```
static ArrayList<Integer> quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> array){

    if (array.size() <=1){
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        return a;
    }

    int pivotIndex = array.size() / 2;

    int pivot = array.get(pivotIndex);
    ArrayList<Integer> left= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> right = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (i!=pivotIndex){
        if (array.get(i) > pivot)
            right.add(array.get(i));
        else
            left.add(array.get(i));
        }

    }
    ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    l.addAll(quickSort(left));
     l.add(pivot);
     l.addAll(quickSort(right)); 

    return l;

}
```

Comment: Please ask some specific question. Any problem you faced with the implementation? Any errors, exceptions you got? Post it here.

Comment: The code runs without exception or error but it doesnt sort the data!

Answer (score 3):

One glaring error is that arrays of size one are not handled correctly. It's important to get this right since this is one of the base cases for the recursion.

Comment: what is your suggestion for the base case?

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
if (array.size() <=1) {
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    return a;
}
```

use

```
   if (array.size() <=1){
   return array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with this algorithm - you're creating new ArrayLists for each invocation of the function. In this way you nullify the best thing about QuickSort - sorting in place without any additional memory. Try to work only with the first given **array**.